# Zapier and Pythoneverywhere smtp issues

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib, pythonanywhere, zapier

I've been using Zapier and Pythoneverywhere for some backend stuff using Python, and recently I've been getting a 534 error as follows:

`File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 622, in login raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp) SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuE\n5.7.14 VyQLZTijmufE25PUD9vfTLC3FrnAU5nlNWptaIGEMv5N2OJ6SeJr1k1LxC0yuXv1eZAMYw\n5.7.14 ejmvetuDKIBX3L9MYPGLY75EUlIuSiSHEmp-0wpi6gazhumwltHXV07K9Q0lou0t4ky1QN\n5.7.14 7jnbEIhA1W6ceSVqvdwtH7wAOKsUhDlwYhkd3-81UClaoJ7sWRCICCJJW4iQxpIDNE4Yqr\n5.7.14 Tto1BfHEYh77B5bZkRiu5BxvjOfCY> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14 Learn more at\n5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 t1sm124763qtt.25 - gsmtp'"`

I'm pretty sure it isn't an issue with the code, because I've been using it for months. I'll post some test code for good measure, but really I'm wondering if anyone else has been getting the error and if they have figured out a solution.

```
    import smtplib
    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
    company = 'daves burgers'
    dealtype = '409a'
    analyst = 'Nate'
    itemId = '92081920'
    salesRep = 'shawn olsen'
    companyLink = 'html link to company'
    analystFirst = (analyst.split(' ',2))[0]
    salesRepFirst = (salesRep.split(' ',2))[0]
    contactEmail = 'contact@sana.com'
    analystEmail = "analyst@gmail.com"
    emailPass = "password"
    html = """<html>A bunch of html></html>"""
    fromaddr = analystEmail
    bcc = ['bcc@bcc.com']
    firstName=  'dave'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = analyst
    msg['Subject'] ="Scalar - "+company+" - "+dealtype+" - onboarding"
    body = "Thanks "+salesRepFirst+".\n\n"+firstName+",\n\nPleased to e-meet you. We're looking forward to working on your valuation! To begin the onboarding process, please follow this link (link to onboarding "+companyLink+"/"+itemId+") to our onboarding platform, where you will be asked to verify information about your company as well as provide the necessary documentation for the valuation to begin. Should any questions arise while you're gathering the necessary docs, please reach out to me.\n\nOnce we receive the docs, we'll get started right away and will turn around the draft within 5-7 business days. We'll most likely want to set up a call with you once we've started the analysis. I'll reach out to you at that point.\n\nThanks!"
    msg['To'] = contactEmail
    toaddr = contactEmail
    toaddrs = [toaddr] + bcc
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(html,'html'))
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(analystEmail,emailPass)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
```

This error occurs no matter which email account I login to from Zapier or Pythonanywhere (Also, worth noting is that all the accounts have "less secure apps" allowed in the settings).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this fixed it, but I made one change to this section of the code:

```
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
```

And changed it to be:

```
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
```

As per this ([Error Sending Email (Gmail) Via Python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294897/error-sending-email-gmail-via-python-2-6)) forum post.